# How to prevent compile inner html inside some tags?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a custom component, that has inner html with `{{braces}}`, calling functions like `v-on:click="click()"` and other. I want to read this html and then work with it.

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['clmn'];
Vue.component("tbln", {
  template: `<div></div>`,
  functional: true,
  render: (h, ctx) => {
    var children = ctx.children.filter(vnode => vnode.tag);
    console.log(children)
    if (ctx.props.show) {
      return children[0]
    } else {
      return children[0].children
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <tbln>
    <clmn bind="data" sort="data" align="left"></clmn>
    <clmn no-sort>
        <div>{{ text }}</div>
    </clmn>
    <clmn bind="vvv" sort-func="func"></clmn>

  </tbln>
</div>
```

But Vue automatically compiles full and throws errors.

How to prevent compile inner html in some tags?

I tried different methods to solve this problem, but all did not help me:

- I added tag into `Vue.config.ignoredElements`. Not working, i catch an error
- `v-pre` and `template` not a solution, I just need to make the
  code easy to understand

Comment: Why include components that you don't want compiled?

Comment: @Dan for having a structure of data, that will be received from server and will be used later for displaying ion the page

Comment: This would not be the way to achieve that.  Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do (in detail) instead.